# how to remove continuously duplicate value from vector in clojure?

Tags: clojure

I want to remove the continuously duplicate value from vector in clojure

```
input：[1 1 1 2 2 1 1 3 3]

output：[1 2 1 3]
```

how to achieve it?

Comment: What did you try? Where are you stuck at?

Comment: in case you need do actually implement this (without `dedupe`) the easiest would be `(mapv first (partition-by identity data))`

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, tracebacks, etc.). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Check the [FAQ] and [ask].

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is what [clojure.core/dedupe](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/dedupe) does.